# how to convert byte[] to image

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, byte

how to convert byte[] to Bitmap

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(img_bytes, 0, img_bytes.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
Bitmap obj = new Bitmap(ms); // Error: Parameter is not valid
```

tried to convert byte[] to Bitmap but i get error "Parameter is not valid"

Comment: What type of image is it?

Comment: type of image is *bmp

Comment: Try the [ImageConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageconverter) class -- Make sure the image is actually a BMP, not another non compatible image type in a file with the `.bmp` extension (the first 5 bytes can tell you that) -- You should also explain where the byte array comes from

Comment: @Jimi fairly sure `new Bitmap` does the same thing though. If it can't identify it, it's just not a valid image file format.

Comment: @Nyerguds Of course. I suggested this to avoid custom code for the conversion, because the ImageConverter behavior is known (though it does something similar) and it also tries to determine whether it's an OLE-packaged bitmap, so the exception *could* be different and, hopefully, more revealing (which is not guaranteed at all, but - given the very basic information posted here - eventually useful). The rest of the comment is more self-explanatory

Answer (score 1):

There are two general ways to represent image data in binary. Either as a *image file* or as *raw data*

If you have a image file the posted code is correct. But it might fail if the image format is unknown, or the file is damaged or incomplete. You can start by checking that the file starts with the file signature of a bmp file: `42 4D`, or a file signature of some [other image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). You should also verify the code by opening a known good bmp file and verify that it works. You could also save your data to a file and try opening it with a third part tool.

The other option is that you have raw image data, i.e. a buffer containing all the pixel values. But this is not usable unless you also have at least:

- Image width or stride (ideally both)
- Pixel format

Comment: "checking that the file starts with the file signature of a bmp file" is a bit naïve; the image data can be bmp, png, jpg, gif, tiff, and probably a bunch more.

Comment: @Nyerguds OP specified that it was a bmp file in the comments, other formats have other signatures that can be checked.